# Is there a way to verify the LinkedList<String> is in descending order?

Tags: java, string, compareto

```
public static boolean verifyRecords(LinkedList<String> recordList, String order) throws Exception {

 /*To check ascending order*/
    if("Ascending".equalsIgnoreCase(order) || "A".equalsIgnoreCase(order)) {
        String previous = new String();
        for(String current : recordList) {
            if(current.compareTo(previous) < 0) 
                return false;
            previous = current;
        }
    } else if("Descending".equalsIgnoreCase(order) || "D".equalsIgnoreCase(order)) 
   {  
        for(String current : recordList) {
            if(current.compareTo(previous) > 0) 
                return false;
            previous = current;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Here, I am giving new String(), i.e. Empty, string to start with for Ascending order. But for Descending order, what should be the starting String to start descending order comparison the i should use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just start by comparing the second element to the first, instead of starting by comparing the first to a fictive element.

Comment: you only need to verify then why you are looping untll end of the element, what if your between elements are not sorted, you should only loop to chekc if the things are correct else break and dont go further.

Comment: If those linked lists are not big, and this is somewhere in a test case, you can just copy the input into a new collection, sort that and then compare the sorted with the input.

Comment: Instead of `String previous = new String();` use `String previous = null`. In loop ignore the condition `if(previous == null)`

Comment: also check out http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/r03/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.java#Ordering.isOrdered%28java.lang.Iterable%29

Comment: Consider using comparisons like `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`. If list contains two of the same string, then your method will not consider collection as ordered correctly even if all other elements are ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to loop untill the last element, you can compare any uneven thing and break from there to achieve your results or verify the list.

```
if ("Ascending".equalsIgnoreCase(order) || "A".equalsIgnoreCase(order)) {
        for (int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++) {
            if (recordList.get(i - 1).compareTo(recordList.get(i)) > 0) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    } else if ("Descending".equalsIgnoreCase(order)
            || "D".equalsIgnoreCase(order)) {
        for (int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++) {
            if (recordList.get(i - 1).compareTo(recordList.get(i)) < 0) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }
        }


    }
    return isSorted;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Collections.reverse(list) to compare. The idea is to create a shallow copy of the recordList, sort in descending order and compare them.

```
    LinkedList<String> recordList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","B", "c"));
    LinkedList<String> validateList = new LinkedList<String>(recordList);
    Collections.sort(validateList); // sorts in ascending order
    Collections.reverse(validateList); // reverses the ascending ordered list
    System.out.println(recordList.equals(validateList));
```

Comment: Thanks @FelixDombek for pointing out. The list.sort() was missing. It has to precede the list.reverse(). Added the missing step in the answer now.